# Generating all non-duplicate subsequences with a string that has repeated characters

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to solve a problem where I am given a string with repeated characters in it and I am supposed to generate all unique subsequences.

I now how to generate all subsequences ignoring the duplicate part or assuming that there are no repeated characters: (p stands for process, data is used for adding characters from process)

```
public static ArrayList generate(String process,String data){
    if(data.isEmpty()){
        ArrayList <String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(process);
        return temp;
    }
    ArrayList <String> left = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <String> right = new ArrayList<>();
    left = generate(process+data.charAt(0),data.substring(1));
    right = generate(process,data.substring(1));

    left.addAll(right);
    return left;
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this for non-duplicate subsequences. I am trying to check at every base condition if we have already added that string in our arraylist, but it still gives me duplicated in answer in this code: (up is unprocessed same as data in the above code, p is processed or string passed from main initially)

```
public static ArrayList<String> generateNonDuplicate(String up, String p,ArrayList <String> current){
    if(up.isEmpty()){
        if(current.contains(p)){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        ArrayList <String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(p);
        return temp;
    }

    ArrayList <String> left = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <String> right = new ArrayList<>();        
    left=generateNonDuplicate(up.substring(1), p+up.charAt(0), left);
    right=generateNonDuplicate(up.substring(1), p, right);
    
    left.addAll(right);

    return left;
}
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: That C++ tag was just attracting the wrong kind of attention so I removed it. OK. Somehow someone else removed it. Dueling edits, I guess.

Comment: `current` is always empty.  Instead of merging results from `generateNonDuplicate`, you should pass in a destination list that it adds to.  Note: I see in comments that you don't want to hear about any better algorithms, but this algorithm takes a horribly long time.  I won't provide a fix in an answer, because I couldn't bear to have my name underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have gotten this with a simple Google search. Here is a naive solution, from GeeksforGeeks. Find more solutions on this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-subsequences/

```
// java program to print distinct
// subsequences of a given string
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;

class GFG {
    // Function for generating the subsequences
    public static void subsequences(Set<String> sn,
                                    char[] s, char[] op,
                                    int i, int j, int n)
    {
        // Base Case
        if (i == n) {
            op[j] = '\0';

            // Insert each generated
            // subsequence into the set
            sn.add(String.valueOf(op));
            return;
        }

        // Recursive Case
        else {
            // When a particular character is taken
            op[j] = s[i];
            subsequences(sn, s, op, i + 1, j + 1, n);

            // When a particular character isn't taken
            subsequences(sn, s, op, i + 1, j, n);
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[] str = { 'g', 'g', 'g' };
        int m = str.length;
        int n = (int)Math.pow(2, m) + 1;

        // Create an empty set to store the subsequences
        Set<String> sn = new HashSet<String>();

        // Output array for storing
        // the generating subsequences
        // in each call
        char[] op = new char[m + 1]; // extra one for having
                                    // \0 at the end

        // Function Call
        subsequences(sn, str, op, 0, 0, m);

        // Output will be the number
        // of elements in the set
        System.out.println(sn.size());
        sn.clear();

        // This code is contributed by Aditya Sharma
    }
}
```

Comment: I did google search and saw this solution. They have used a hashset which I am not familiar with. I wanted to see how I can proceed with my own code and not change the code completely to something that works but I dont understand

Comment: @my_neme_eh_jeffn a hashset is a structure that only stores unique elements. For example if your set has {1,2,3} in it and you add 3 than you will still have {1,2,3}. Your solution will take long as hell, but I will try to provide a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Going for it with a 2nd try. I wasn't able to fix your solution, but if you want to give with a similar approach 2 solutions would be:

1. Go with the original solution and just remove the duplicates at the end. You can do this by putting the solution to a set:

   HashSet a = new HashSet<>(generate("", "aabc"));

Result:

```
[aa, , ab, a, bc, aac, ac, b, aab, abc, c, aabc]
```

If you really want to use a recursive solution with O(2^N) complexity, than here is a similar solution from [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-distinct-subsequences-of-array-using-backtracking/):

```
// Java program to implement
// the above approach
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class GFG{
    
// Function to generate all distinct
// subsequences of the array using backtracking
public static void backtrack(ArrayList<Integer> nums,
                            int start,
                            ArrayList<Integer> curr_set)
{
    System.out.print(curr_set + " ");

    for(int i = start; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        
        // If the current element is repeating
        if (i > start &&
            nums.get(i) == nums.get(i - 1))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Include current element
        // into the subsequence
        curr_set.add(nums.get(i));

        // Proceed to the remaining array
        // to generate subsequences
        // including current array element
        backtrack(nums, i + 1, curr_set);

        // Remove current element
        // from the subsequence
        curr_set.remove(curr_set.size() - 1);
    }
}

// Function to sort the array and generate
// subsequences using Backtracking
public static void AllSubsets(ArrayList<Integer> nums)
{

    // Stores the current
    // subsequence
    ArrayList<Integer> curr_set = new ArrayList<>();

    // Sort the vector
    Collections.sort(nums);

    // Backtrack function to
    // generate subsequences
    backtrack(nums, 0, curr_set);
}

// Driver Code
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> v = new ArrayList<>();
    v.add(1);
    v.add(2);
    v.add(2);
    
    // Function call
    AllSubsets(v);
}
}

// This code is contributed by hemanthswarna1506
```